# IIS7.5 PHP WSDL cache

Tags: php, iis, caching, wsdl

I am trying to setup a PHP SOAP WSDL cache working on an IIS 7.5.
Settings from php.ini(displayed via PHPInfo) are as follows:
`soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1`
`soap.wsdl_cache_dir=/tmp`
`soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400`
`soap.wsdl_cache=1`
`soap.wsdl_cache_limit=100`
I have wincache 1.1.(0630) installed, PHP=5.2.17(FastCGI x86)

I don't see any cached WSDL files in /tmp directory and doing SOAP calls is very slow. Did I missed smething or there is no option to setup WSDL caching using IIS/PHP?
Rgds,
Frenk

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! Slow requests, same IIS & PHP 5.3.1 and same PHP-Soap-Conf (except limit=5). So here is my solution:

I ve changed the `wsdl_cache_dir` from `/tmp` (within the php directory) to `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP` and now a wsdl file is generated within the windows-temp dir & everything seems to work.
I think php under IIS can only write to the windows temp directory without any modification.

Hope it works for you too,

Lucian